# Antlr4 Visitor several rule contexts

Tags: antlr4

I've a grammar like that:

```
search
 : K_SEARCH entity
 ( K_QUERY expr )?
 ( K_FILTER expr )?
;
```

As you can see I've two optional `expr`.

I've created my Visitor, and I'm able to get access to `entity`, `K_QUERY` and `K_FILTER`. `SearchContext` provides a `List<ExprContext>` in order to get a list of all `expr`. However, how can I know with expression is a `K_QUERY expr` or a `K_FILTER expr`?

```
public class LivingQueryVisitor extends LivingDSLBaseVisitor<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void visitSearch(SearchContext ctx) {
        this.query = search(this.getEntityPath(ctx));
        //???????????????????????
        List<ExprContext> exprs = ctx.expr();
        //???????????????????????
        return super.visitSearch(ctx);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `search` a complete rule, or are you missing `|` before lines `( K_QUERY expr )?` and `( K_FILTER expr )?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just label the two `expr` terms.

```
search : K_SEARCH entity
       ( K_QUERY  q=expr )?
       ( K_FILTER f=expr )?
;
```

Antlr will generate two additional variables within the SearchContext class:

```
ExprContext q;
ExprContext f;
```

The values will be non-null *iff* the corresponding subterms matched.

Comment: I've ask another question on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468757/bind-antlr4-subrules-of-a-rule).

Answer (score 1):

If you do now want to change the grammar that will enable you to do it in more elegant way, you can just use index. As there are two 'expr' in the rule, you expr[0] will be K_Query expression and expr[1] will be K_filter expresssion provided there are both tokens present. (K_Query and K_filter).

If not, expr[0] will be the expression of the existing token.